# jQuery dataTables header click custom event

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I add a custom click event for some of the table headers in the datatable. I have removed the default sorting event from every column except 1st column. So I want to add the custom event to those columns. And I want to find the index of the column the user clicked.

What I have tried so far is this. But I can't figure out how to find the index of the column user clicked.

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": data_set,
    "columns": column_titles,
    "columnDefs": column_defs
} );

$('#example thead').on( 'click', 'th', function () {         
    alert( 'Column clicked on: ');
} );
```

P.S.
I have found this article https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().header() and followed it. But when I call table.cell() , it gives an error.

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    var idx = table.cell( this ).index().column;
    var title = table.column( idx ).header();

    alert( 'Column title clicked on: '+$(title).html() );
 } );
```

Comment: what version of datatables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet I had found was correct except for one small piece.

By using the below code it correctly create the dataTable.

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": data_set,
    "columns": column_titles,
    "columnDefs": column_defs
} );
```

But it does not correctly select the table. So later when I try to access the table object it does not have the method "cell".

Code should be corrected as

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {...
```

So now the table has the "cell" method.

So the final code will be as below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": data_set,
    "columns": column_titles,
    "columnDefs": column_defs
} );

$("#example").find("thead").on('click', 'th', function(){
    var col_idx =  table.column(this).index();
    console.log("colId = " + col_idx);
});
```

Comment: Yes, correct when you click on `<td>`'s , eg on data - but it fails when you click on the headers.

Comment: attention: if dataTable with `scrollY`,
  it will create a separate table for header, original thead will hidden

Answer (score 4):

```
var table = $(`#mytable`).DataTable({
    ...
});

var headers = table.columns().header().toArray();

$(headers).on('click', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: You if you want to get column name then you can try this.

var headers = table.columns().header().toArray();

  $(headers).on('click', function (e) {
   // do something
   console.log("column Name", e.target.innerHTML);
  });

Answer (score 2):

You get the index when clicking on headers like this :

```
$('#example thead').on('click', 'th', function () {
  var index = table.column(this).index();
  alert('index : '+index);
});
```

This works with hidden columns, reordered columns ans so on as well.

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1kjooq9w/**

Comment: My problem was the way I selected my table. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27650447/1537365

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zwkggt7r/3/

Try it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable();
    table.on('click', 'th', function() {
        var info = table.fnSettings().aaSorting;
        var idx = info[0][0];
        alert(idx);
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the latest version of DataTables (Error: table.fnSettings is not a function)..

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long while since I used DataTables, but I think you can achieve it with `cell().index()`.  Check out the doc: https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().index()

```
$('#example thead').on('click', 'th', function () {         
    alert( 'Column clicked on: ' + table.cell(this).index().column);
});
```

Comment: I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when I try this

Comment: My problem was the way I selected my table. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27650447/1537365

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using **order** method of the table. My technique works well.

We need to do two things here.

- Get current column index
- Apply ascending or descending action on particular column on click of a icon

Here let us assume we have a button or link to which **click** to bind.

```
$(".arrow-sort-ascending").bind("click", {
 // Sorting should happen here
}
```

#### Getting column index

I use generic way to get column name. If you are using Jquery, we can fetch the column index using this.

```
myColumn = $(parent).prevAll().length
```

where **parent** should be the **th** of particular column.

#### Applying ascending or descending sort

```
 // ascending
 myTable.order([myColumn, "asc"]).draw()
```

So if we put the code in a single section, it looks like this.

```
table = myTable // This is datatable you initialized

$(".arrow-sort-ascending").bind("click", {table: table}, function(event){
    parent = $(event.target).parent()
    myIndex = $(parent).prevAll().length;
    table.order([myIndex, "asc"]).draw()
}
```

So whenever we click the arrrow-up icon, it sorts the clicked column.